# MODx Create dynamic frontend page / display manager page without login

Tags: php, dynamic, custom-controls, modx, modx-revolution

Is there some frontend controller to create dynamic page with some custom created URL without add them from Manager Resource panel? I want to create some secret page (and perform some actions there) but it shouldn't be seen in Manager for anyone (even admin or myself). I'm pretty newbie in ModX so any direct solutions will be appreciated.

Or...
I've custom controller in Manager and I can access it by `/manager/?a=some/controller`. Is there any way to display it without login user?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but the system will always leave traces of existence of such code.

One possible solution is to have a PHP file in the file system that is not directly in the Modx System, but external. You can read how this is done in [Loading Modx Externally](http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/other-development-resources/loading-modx-externally).

Another solution might be to create a Plugin and fire this Plugin on `OnPageNotFound`. In this plugin you can analyze the query string and check if it is the "secret" URL you'd like to use.

Again, both solutions leave traces, but they will not show up in the Resources tree.